comparing the performance of a x86 processor with gem5
I'm trying to create a gem5 implementation that is close to a x86 processor in terms of performance. However, I'm not sure which statistic I can use to compare the performance of the two.
I was thinking of comparing the time it takes to execute a program, but I feel like this is inaccurate. Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do to compare the two?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
